# sending data through emails between different sql servers

Tags: sql-server, email, service, service-broker

I have a sql server external to our organisation that sends automated emails with a few basics pieces of data to a staff members mail box.

It's then manually transcribed into a csv file which is imported through ssis into our sql server.

Is there a way to directly send the email to our SQL server so it can process the data automatically ?

I have no control over the external servers setup or output.

Comment: I know this can be done with coldfusion.  That means it could probably also be done with other programming languages.  Set up an email address to receive the files and write a program that reads the mail and does what needs to be done with the file.

Answer (score 0):

“Is there a way to directly send the email to our SQL server so it can process the data automatically?” – nopes. There is no default supported way to do this. You would need to create a custom application that will

1. Check the mailbox
2. Parse the results
3. Insert results into database

The application doesn’t have to be on the sever itself but it needs to be able to connect to it of course.